# Mapping Orders With JPA and Play Framework

Tags: jpa, playframework

I'm using play framework 1.2.4 and i'm preparing an meal order system. So i want to get them in a map.

```
package models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity
public class Order extends Model{


Map<Item, Float> orders;

Table table;
Date date;  

public Order(Map<Item, Float> orders, Table table) {
    super();
    this.orders = orders;
    this.table = table;
    date = new Date();
}
```

}

But when i start the application it gives this error,

JPA error
A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: Order, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(orders)]

How can i store orders like 1 porsion pizza, 1.5 porsion soup etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change table name for the entity Order by using @Table annotation. In many DBMS "order" is a reserved word.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="apporder")
public class Order extends Model {
    // ...
}
```

About order items: you need other entity for storing this data. For example:

### OrderItem.java

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.jpa.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

@Entity
public class OrderItem extends Model {

    @ManyToOne
    public Order order;

    @ManyToOne
    public Item item;

    public Float qty;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your map needs to be annotated if you want it managed by jpa

```
@ElementCollection
Map<Item, Float> orders;
```

Comment: it works. Thank you... Can you offer a page like cheatsheet, shows us this notations? :)

Comment: Now i realized, it gives this errors and some tables will not be created... :S
20:29:27,515 ERROR ~ Unsuccessful: create table Order (id bigint not null auto_increment, date datetime, table tinyblob, primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
20:29:27,515 ERROR ~ You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (id bigint not null auto_increment, date datetime, table tinyblob, primary' at line 1

Comment: 20:29:27,599 ERROR ~ Unsuccessful: create table Table (id bigint not null auto_increment, number integer, primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
20:29:27,599 ERROR ~ You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Table (id bigint not null auto_increment, number integer, primary key (id)) ENGI' at line 1
20:29:27,601 ERROR ~ Unsuccessful: alter table Order_orders_price add index FK7A5564E0F487F656 (Order_id), add constraint FK7A5564E0F487F656 foreign key (Order_id) references Order (id)

Comment: 20:29:27,601 ERROR ~ You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (id)' at line 1
20:29:27,831 INFO  ~ Application 'rms' is now started !

Comment: This is a standard JPA annotation so there is no need to add it to the Play cheat sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Add a **Serving** class with a *float* (number of helpings) and an **Item** (the thing being served). Then add a *Set<Serving>* to the Order class. Makes way more sense than a Map for such information.